# T-SQL varchar URL showing %0D%0A at end

Tags: sql, url, power-automate

I have a URL stored as VARCHAR in SQL Server but when I try to select the URL through Power Automate (Using Execute SQL statement) and use it on a browser it adds %0D%0A

I have remove CR, LR & Trimmed and it still appears

In SQL it appears as [www.company.co.uk/company/menu.nsf](http://www.company.co.uk/company/menu.nsf) 
In Power Automate I see [www.company.co.uk/company/menu.nsf%0D%0A](http://www.company.co.uk/company/menu.nsf%0D%0A)